# Autohotkey FileAppend Help Please

Tags: autohotkey

I cannot append DDL contents along side two files contents. the two files are topCode.txt and bottomCode.txt.....DLL contents must be in between the two file.
I hope this is better way to explain.

```
Gui, Color, 008AB8
Gui 1:Show, x131 y91 h379 w479, Rotation Helper

Gui, Add, DropDownList,x76 y27 w50 h20 r10 gLoad vDDL, 1||2|3
                    Gui, Add, Text, x16 y27 w50 h20 +Center, Number
Gui, Add, Edit, x76 y57 w50 h20 vhotkey,
                    Gui, Add, Text, x16 y57 w50 h20 +Center, Hotkey
Gui, Add, Edit, x76 y87 w50 h20 vcolor,
                    Gui, Add, Text, x16 y87 w50 h20 +Center, Color
Gui, Add, Edit, x76 y117 w50 h20 vX1,
                    Gui, Add, Text, x16 y117 w50 h20 +Center, X1 

Gui, Add, Button, x146 y337 w100 h30 gClear, Clear Enteries
Gui, Add, Button, x256 y337 w100 h30 gSave, Save
Gui, Add, Button, x366 y337 w90 h30 gLoad, Load
Gui, Add, GroupBox, x6 y7 w450 h250 , Settings

return

Clear:
GuiControl, , hotkey, %Subject%
GuiControl, , color, %Subject%
GuiControl, , X1, %Subject%


Return

Save:
Gui, Submit, NoHide

IniWrite,%hotkey%, %a_Workingdir%\Iniread.ini, List%DDL%, List1
IniWrite,%color%, %a_Workingdir%\Iniread.ini, List%DDL%, List2
IniWrite,%X1%, %a_Workingdir%\Iniread.ini, List%DDL%, List3


return

Load:
Gui, Submit, NoHide

Iniread, Read, %a_workingdir%\Iniread.ini, List%DDL%, List1
Iniread,Read2, %a_Workingdir%\Iniread.ini, List%DDL%, List2
Iniread,newX1, %a_Workingdir%\Iniread.ini, List%DDL%, List3


GuiControl,, hotkey, %Read%
GuiControl,, color, %Read2%
GuiControl,, X1, %newX1%

NewColor = PixelSearch, %AbilityNameX%, %AbilityNameY%, %newX1%, %newY1%, %newX2%, %newY2%, %Read2%, 3, Fast if !ErrorLevel SendInput {%Read% down}{%Read% up}  
FileRead, topCode, %A_ScriptDir%\topCode.txt
FileRead, bottomCode, %A_ScriptDir%\bottomCode.txt

FileAppend,
(
%topCode%,%NewColor%,%bottomCode%
), %A_ScriptDir%\PasteToRotationFile.ahk
```

return

Comment: Please minify your code to only contain relevant parts and explain more precisely what exactly you want.

Comment: Its very hard to explain, I have explained to Authotkey and they told me that is not possible... this website is full of people who would down vote people without patience.

Comment: At least reduce your code to the relevant parts then! I mean you didn't even put any comments in your code, what are you expecting? When asking a question on StackOverflow you are supposed to show effort and try your best to explain your problem and also generalize it as much as possible. I can't see that you did any of that.

Comment: Ok Mr. Forivin, I appreciate your help sir, I have explained my question in a different way, in addition, the code is reduced

Answer (score 2):

The File stuff is below the `Load:` label so it gets executed every time you use the Load button. And `FileAppend` **appends** to a file so you have to delete it **before**.

Your file part should robably look like this (wild guess):

```
NewColor = PixelSearch, %AbilityNameX%, %AbilityNameY%, %newX1%, %newY1%, %newX2%, %newY2%, %Read2%, 3, Fast if !ErrorLevel SendInput {%Read% down}{%Read% up}  
FileRead, topCode, %A_ScriptDir%\topCode.txt
FileRead, bottomCode, %A_ScriptDir%\bottomCode.txt
FileDelete, %A_ScriptDir%\PasteToRotationFile.ahk
FileAppend,
(
%topCode%,%NewColor%,%bottomCode%
), %A_ScriptDir%\PasteToRotationFile.ahk
```

Improve your question and i will adapt this answer.

Comment: Thnx for the help the code works but the problem it wont append more than 1 time... the DLL inputs go in the middle of the two file- topCode.txt and bottomCode.txt but only one input is showing.